# How To Select YEAR() MONTH() DAY() In Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I use this code select object case MONTH
This my function in repository

```
    public function findProductByCustomerIdGroupByCodeMc($id,$magasin,$periode)
    {

    $emConfig = $this->getEntityManager()->getConfiguration();
        $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('YEAR', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year');
        $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('MONTH', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month');
        $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('DAY', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day');

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('lead')
                    ->select('lead')
                    ->from('BOGeneralBundle:EtLeads', 'l')
                     if($periode != "0") 
                     {
                      $qb->andWhere('MONTH(l.dataCreated) = :periode')
                             ->setParameter('periode', $periode);
                     }
        return$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

and put conduction because I have option for all Month and it value = 0
and the page display this message

> Fatal error: Class 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month' not found

Comment: `DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month` class exists ?

Comment: Should I created it ? if yes were ?

Comment: See my answer pls :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Doctrine2, you have to register your own function to recognize YEAR() MONTH() and DAY() in DQL

To do this you can install [this](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) bundle via composer. Just add it to your `composer.json` and then `php composer.phar update beberlei/DoctrineExtensions`

```
"beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "*",
```

Then you can register functions to your ORM

```
doctrine:
    orm:
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
      entity_managers:
        default:
          auto_mapping: true
          dql:
            datetime_functions:
              DAY: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
              MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
              YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

[This](https://simukti.net/blog/2012/04/05/how-to-select-year-month-day-in-doctrine2.html) article talks about this too.

Comment: what is the type of $periode ? is it integer or what ??